# Alamofire- getting 'No such module' error after successful Pod install

Tags: swift3, alamofire, xcode8, ios10

Xcode 8, Swift3, cocoapods 1.1+, ios10

I'm getting error - No such module. Below is my pod file and steps I followed. I even looked at same issues from previous versions and solutions mentioned in other threads didn't work.

Setup

Fresh, brand new Xcode 8 project.
Added Alamofire to my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target ‘weatherkaka’ do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
end
```

Ran the command $ pod install
Install worked fine, and project compiles via workspace file
Opened xcworkspace file 
Import: import AlamoFire
I get the error: "No such module: Alamofire".

What am I missing?

Note: I've done clean, re-open Xcode, clean more, re-compile etc. I've added the Alamofire framework to Linked Frameworks and Build phases.

Comment: Why the down vote ? Care to explain ? Its a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 0):

You might get this error for the first time but try to run that project once and it might go away. Also you can `command+click` the import Alamofire and check that it points to the Alamofire.

You must be using **projectName.xcworkspace** not the **xcodeproj**.

Comment: I had to do a pod set up for some reason to fix the issue. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Revanth Yes if the pods aren't correctly set up then you need to install it again.